# Docker Copy doesn't appear to have relative patn

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm building a docker container, but it seems to not be using the relative path to my `DOCKERFILE`, and using one in `ProgramData` instead.

I've never had this sort of issue before (New build laptop). This happens on both Windows and Linux containers (Slightly different path)

DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ./bin/Release/PublishOutput .
```

BuildOutput

```
C:\Workspaces\SoftwareTrunk\Yeti\src\ExportAPI>docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
 ---> 962fe4c099b1
Step 2/4 : ARG source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03006439cd6a
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dedd0aed0b62
Step 4/4 : COPY bin/Release/PublishOutput .
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder780251894\bin\Release\PublishOutput: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by Visual Studio Docker Integration.

It adds a `.dockerignore` with the following

So it pretty much ignores everything and falls back to a known build directory - removing the `*` fixed it.

```
*
!obj\Docker\publish\*
!obj\Docker\empty\
```